# Sql query expected ';'

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

im having a slight problem where my sql query is not working since it keeps giving me this erro where it says expected ;, even though i have put a semi collan there. im quite new to java so any help would be appriticated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;



     public class Manager {
         Connection con;
         Statement st;
         ResultSet rs;

JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
JLabel U = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel P = new JLabel("Password");
JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
JButton b = new JButton("Login");


public Manager()
{
    connect();
    frame();
}
public void connect()
{

try
{    

String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
st = con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
}
public void frame()
{
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(U);
    p.add(t);
    p.add(P);
    p.add(t1);
    p.add(b);

    f.add(p);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
            String User = t.getText().trim();
            String Password =t1.getText().trim();


            String sql = "select User,Password from Table1 where User = '" + User +"'and Password='"+ Password"'";


            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            int count = 0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if(count == 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User found, Acces");
                    }
            else if(count > 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicated User, Access denied");

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Not found");
            }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Manager();
}
```

}

Comment: You should consider use `PreparedStatement` instead of create the whole query in a String

Comment: First off: *use parameterized queries*!  You probably have some closing quote in your field causing the query to break.  Using parameterized queries prevents that from being an issue along with preventing SQL Injection (which your code is *wide open* to).  Secondly:  DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS AS PLAIN TEXT.

Comment: What is the exception message/stack trace?  Also, the `sql` is open to SQL Injection attack - consider using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: SQL injection, plain text passwords, *and* an empty `catch` block.  This code is *inviting* a whole variety of problems.

Comment: FYI: Tooltip for tag `access` says: *DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead.*

Comment: This is a **COMPILE ERROR**, not a runtime error, caused by the missing `+` between `Password` and `"'"` at the ne dof the line, as observed in [answer by @alayor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42703549/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a '+' sign.

Change

`+"'and Password='"+ Password"'";`

to

`+"'and Password='"+ Password + "'";`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a ; in your sql string...somewhat like this( after password)

String sql = "select User,Password from Table1 where User = '" + User +"'and Password='"+ Password"'" + ";";

Answer (score -1):

Despite not answering your question, I believe this deserves the attention of an answer, rules be damned. What you are doing literally costs the world tons of money every year, ruins peoples lives, probably literally kills people as well (I know people who have committed suicide from being financially ruined).

(edit) Seeing what your problem was, this actually *might* fix it for you. Bonus. (/edit)

> ***Please use _Prepared Statements_ in your database accesses. If my identity is stolen and my credit maxed out because you are the cheap programmer my bank hired, then I will round up a gang and we will come find you.***

As soon as someone realizes that your code is insecure, your entire database will crumble from that gaping security hole.

I'll try not to let it bother me if this gets a bunch of downvotes; preventing this security problem is worth it.

It is right in the same API you are using. Create a `PreparedStatement`, do

```
myPreparedStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(
    "select User,Password from Table1 where User = '?'and Password='?'");
```

then execute it with

```
myPreparedStatement.setString(columnUser, user);
myPreparedStatement.setString(columnPass, pass);
myPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

You will be very much  better off. Otherwise, I guarantee your database eventually *will* get hacked (and the rest of your network, depending on how everything is set up).

SQL injections are the bread and butter (and feces) of database attacks. *This one simple trick will save you 99% on your post-hack-attempt bills.*

Comment: Actually, wait a minute... are you storing your passwords as plain text, AND are you just bulk-downloading name/password pairs here? That, on top of your other issue I already addressed, would have been catastrophic for you. What some would call a "resume generating event," except that nobody who knew about it would accept that resume. Make sure you hash the passwords and add some salt, or better yet use some other directory service to do the work for you. At a minimum, run some hashing function on passwords before saving them (and obviously again when you authenticate)